# Referencing a typescript interface field

Tags: typescript

I am creating a react component and I would like to pass to it a reference to a field in an interface.

What does that mean? For example,

```
interface Person {
name: String
}
```

I would like to be able to pass a ref to Person::name, so that inside the component, I will be able to set this field on an actual instance. I know I can do with a function - (p: Person) -> p.name = "the name"

but that just creates boilerplate code.

I also know that I can pass "name" as a string, but that is susceptible to misspelling and refactor. I want to use the power of type safety.

Thx

Answer (score 2):

From what I can understand from your question, you want to pass the `name` property of the `Person` interface to a component. This can be achieved using the [`Pick`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys) utility type provided by TypeScript, like this:

```
interface Props {
  name: Pick<Person, "name">;
}
export const Component: React.FC<Props> = (
  props: Props
): React.ReactElement<Props> => {
  // ....
};
```

Comment: This is ok, but it forces me to use the string "name" which I don't want to do - because when this solution scales, I might refactor name to name2, but "name" will still be there

Comment: Are you talking about `props.name` or `name` field in the Person interface?

Comment: Compiler will tell you "name2 does not exist" when you refactor

Comment: Still not clear. I don't see any useful way of extracting the string "name" from this type.

My objective is to pass it in as a property to a react component that can get many of these field names.

Problem is I cannot seem to instantiate this type to get its fields